# how to catch exception in sqllite transaction - java android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

SO I am writing a database manager for android, and in that class will be a method for writing to a table of that database..

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
          //DO some db writing
          db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
          db.endTransaction();
        }
```

my understanding is that this will automatically rollback the data should the transaction not be set to successful as it is in the try, but how do i catch if it was not successful so i can notify the user on success or rollback

Comment: I use getWritableDatabase() if I want to write to SQLite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just put the catch block before the finally block

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
          //DO some db writing
          db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }catch(Exception e){
           // here you can catch all the exceptions
           e.printStack();
        } finally {
          db.endTransaction();
        }
```

examples for try catch

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=293

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html

Answer (score 0):

For me using `e.printStackTrace();` worked instead of `e.printStack();`

```
SQLiteHelper dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(mContext);
        mDatabase = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        mDatabase.beginTransaction();

        try {

        }catch(Exception e){
            // here you can catch all the exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            mDatabase.endTransaction();
        }

        mDatabase.close();
```